# How to create subset columns in a basic database table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am working on an IEEE paper on feature and sub-set feature selection based on clustering.

I have created a simple login page for the users. 
Also, I have created a table called '`categories`' which has

```
ID_no
Main_catg
sub_catg_id
sub_catg
```

I can't figure out how to enter the data in such a way that I can relate these fields for example,

```
insert into categories values('1','education','1.1','computerscience');
```

How do I create sub-categories? I just want the user to be able to view all the main categories, select a required one and view the sub-categories under that and then be able to upload or download documents accordingly.

This is probably a really basic question but help would be greatly appreciated ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your table structure a bit. This is a rough idea

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `sub_category`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sub_category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `main_category` (`id`);
```

Then in your program logic look at both main_category and sub_category when creating the display.